# CSS and JS File Not loaded

Tags: javascript, css, spring, myeclipse

[image]

This is my project Structure when i am trying to run this project on server CSS and JS file is not able to load.

below are the code i am using to add CSS/JS

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

I am Using MyEclipse as IDE

Comment: did anybody see the code, 'cause i didn't maybe im blind

Comment: now u can See it @LukasA

Answer (score 0):

If you are using in jsp, try using like this

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/form.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put your web project name before the address path of your css file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/YourProjectName/css/XXX.css" type="text/css">
```

or in a more dynamic way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/XXX.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Define this variables on your jsp.

```
<%
String scheme = request.getScheme();
String serverName = request.getServerName();
int serverPort = request.getServerPort();
String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
String uri = scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort + contextPath ;
String uriGeneral = scheme + "://" + serverName + ":" + serverPort;
%>
```

When you need a css or js just do this:

```
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<%=uriGeneral%>/yourModule/resources/css/Style.css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=uriGeneral%>/YourModule/resources/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```